# Open and edit segments of an html page using Javascript or WYSIWYG

Tags: javascript, html, editor, ckeditor, wysiwyg

for I am making an educational website, with practice problems on there, I have a private login area for the teacher, and I was wondering if it was possible to edit the HTML of the other page containing the problems, say if the teacher wished to add more.

I've seen WYSIWYG editors about like the CKEditor, but they have confused me on implementation and capabilities so far, any advice would be much appreciated :)

also if it was possible to have only a segment of the code show, as the teacher using this does not have any experience so the least amount of tech difficult possible would also be greatly appreciated :)

if you have any questions or requests for code please ask :)
thank you :)

```
<div class="main_story" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
                        <p class="sentence">the word to go here -></p>
                        <input id="you" name="input" class="sentence" type="text" size="7">
                        <p class="sentence">is you</p>
                        <button style="float:right" id="correct" onClick="Check('you', 'bShow');">Check answer</button>
                        <input style="float:right" name="bShow" id="bShow" type="checkbox" value="">
                        <p class="sentence" style="float:right">correct</p>
                    </div>
```

it is only really the

and the onClick call from the button that need to be changed, id's may need to be as well, is there any WYSIWYG editor that can edit html in this raw format? :/

Comment: so far I havent really tried anything, Ive done some research and it looks like Javascript wouldn't really work, but WYSIWYG might, however I haven't found a WYSIWYG that can load and save a seperate html page to the one the editor exists in :/
in the edit ive posted the sections of what I would like to be editable/addable.

Comment: what I had originally hoped to do was have two input text fields where the teacher could enter the sentence and missing word, then on submiting javascript would add a new div with this information automatically, i guess that is not possible? :/

Answer (score 3):

Check out aloha: http://aloha-editor.org/

Comment: +1 I liked this link very much. it might be my ediotr for my next project

Comment: it looks good, but i need an editor that can edit the raw sections of a seperate page